# Submitting after login - Android app

Tags: java, android, authentication, http-post, redirect

I'm trying to to submit a form, but before this form I have to log in, so I should do 2 posts in a line, somebody has any idea in how to do that, there is what I have here:

```
    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        String redirectedUrl = getUrl(url);

        // defaultHttpClient
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(redirectedUrl);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", login));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();


        String html = null;
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            try {
                html = streamToString(instream);
            } finally {
                instream.close();
            }
        }
```

The problem there is that when I log in, it just retrieve a response and I can't do anything with, I need to post inside the resource that is protected, somebody has any idea about what I should do. The getUrl function is shown below:

```
private String getUrl(String url) throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpget, context);

    if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        throw new IOException(response.getStatusLine().toString());

    HttpUriRequest currentReq = (HttpUriRequest) context
            .getAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_REQUEST);
    HttpHost currentHost = (HttpHost) context
            .getAttribute(ExecutionContext.HTTP_TARGET_HOST);
    return (currentReq.getURI().isAbsolute()) ? currentReq
            .getURI().toString() : (currentHost.toURI() + currentReq
            .getURI());
}
```

Comment: Actually this part of code is in a kind of HTTP Parser and is called inside one AsyncTask, it's not the question, thanks anyway!

Comment: You got me confused ... is this using Basic HTTP authorization? Then the credentials can be passed in a header field or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, it's working properly, the problem was that I need to submit a page after login is made, what means I should do the same, I'm trying here, if I find a solution I will post here...

Comment: @Fildor it doesn't care about the kind of authentication in this case, it's working with BasicNameValuePair, it's like I'm filling and submitting the form on the page.